# Apache Virtual Hosts - Linking to same website

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I set up two Apache Virtual Hosts for my two forums. When visiting one of them, it links to the root domain page.

Here is my first virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName krypt.fun
    DocumentRoot /var/www/flarum/public

    <Directory /var/www/flarum/public>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/flarum_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/flarum_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =krypt.fun
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

And my second,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName scambaiting.krypt.fun
    DocumentRoot /var/www/scambaiting/public

    <Directory /var/www/scambaiting/public>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/flarum_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/flarum_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However, scambaiting.krypt.fun simply leads to krypt.fun
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you remember to enable the second config file with `a2ensite` then reload Apache? 

Comment: Yes, I have. My virtual host config looks like this: `*:443                  krypt.fun (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/flarum-le-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   scambaiting.krypt.fun (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/scambaiting.conf:1)
`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is being caused by the names of the configuration files. Using a naming structure that will ensure the "default" site (flarum) is always last in the directory will resolve the issue.

For example, you could do this:

1. Change to the `sites-available` directory:

   ```
   cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
   ```
2. Disable the sites that are currently enabled:

   ```
   sudo a2dissite flarum-le-ssl.conf
   sudo a2dissite scambaiting.conf
   ```
3. Rename the configuration files to use a numerical prefix:

   ```
   sudo mv scambaiting.conf 100-scambaiting.conf
   sudo mv flarum-le-ssl.conf 999-flarum-le-ssl.conf
   ```
4. Re-enable the sites:

   ```
   sudo a2ensite flarum-le-ssl.conf
   sudo a2ensite scambaiting.conf
   ```
5. Reload Apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 reload
   ```

   **Note:** Alternatively, you could issue a `restart`.

Now when traffic to the web server is received it will be first compared against the `100` file, then the `999` file. As you add more sites to your server, you can add (and even re-use) these numbers to ensure sites are compared against the Apache enabled sites in a specific order.

You do not need to use numeric prefixes, of course, but the name for the catch-all configuration file should always be last to appear in an alphabetical directory listing.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot. Saved so much of my time :)